# How can I get my database to update more than once in this "foreach" loop, using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach, sql-update

This is in a PHP web page.

I have a link that the user lands on example: `www.example.com/update?attend=1&code[]=4321&code[]=5642&code[]=1842` I need it to update: `foreach` code `attend=1`.

My code so far:

```
...database connect information...

$codes = $_GET['code'];
$invitecode = $_GET['invitecode'];
foreach ($codes as $code) {
print $code;
?><br><?php
$sql = "UPDATE guests SET attend='$isattend' WHERE invitecode=$code";
}

...database close and result...
```

Renders as:

```
4321
5642
1842
Record updated successfully
```

When I check the database only the last value `1842` is set `attend=1`. Prints correct but updates only one?

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you have forget to execute your query before overwrite it.

Comment: Show your complete code!!!

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt thats exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the each sql in foreach but it is better to use IN clause.so you code hit to database only one time.

Comment: I didn't realize I'm doing it wrong I added the `execute` after the `foreach` closed.  But I changed it to be within the brackets, so it executes each one. Thanks. @kiran

Answer (score 2):

if i understand right, so you can change it to:

```
$codes = $_GET['code'];
$invitecode = $_GET['invitecode'];
$sql = "UPDATE guests SET attend='$isattend' WHERE invitecode IN (";
$sep = "";
foreach ($codes as $code) {
print $code;
?><br><?php
$sql = $sql . $sep .$code; 
$sep = ",";
}
$sql = $sql . ")"
```

This will generate **UPDATE guests SET attend='$isattend' WHERE invitecode IN (4321,5642,1842)**

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: It didn't work for some reason...  But what did work and what I didn't realize I'm doing wrong I added the `execute` after the `foreach` closed.  But I changed it to be within the brackets, so it executes each one. Thanks Anyway.